# React-codemirror 2 linting feature not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lint, codemirror, react-codemirror

I have created a react-codemirror 2 component in my react app but the linting feature of the package is not working. I tried browsing other stack overflow questions but since the questions are at least 2 years old it looks like the file structure for the original library i.e. codemirror has been changed and none of the solution seem to work. I also opened an issue in their Github repo but no response on that. Hope you can help, here's the code for my component.

```
import React from "react";
import { UnControlled as CodeMirror } from "react-codemirror2";

import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/lint.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css';



import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/javascript-lint';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/lint.js';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/javascript-hint';


const JsEditor = ({code}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> JavaScript </h1>
      <CodeMirror
        value={code}
        options={{
          gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
          mode: "javascript",
          theme: "material",
          lineNumbers: true,
          lineWrapping: true,
          lint: true,
         
        }}
       
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default JsEditor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lint addon from CodeMirror requires jshint library. If you add it (`npm i jshint`), the following code should work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { UnControlled as CodeMirror } from "react-codemirror2";
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/lint.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css';
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/javascript-lint';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/lint.js';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/javascript-hint';
import { JSHINT } from 'jshint';
window.JSHINT = JSHINT;

const JsEditor = ({ code }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> JavaScript </h1>
      <CodeMirror
        value={code}
        options={{
          gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
          mode: "javascript",
          theme: "material",
          lineNumbers: true,
          lineWrapping: true,
          lint: true,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <JsEditor code={'var widgets =[]; debugger'} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```